# How can I store Vue assets on google cloud storage?

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to store Vue.js assets (js and css) on the external storage (google cloud storage)? How can I reference to these files in production mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's indeed possible to host static assets on Cloud Storage. To do so you have to follow the next steps:

[Create a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets)

1. Open the Cloud Storage browser in the Google Cloud Console.
2. Click Create bucket to open the bucket creation form.
3. Select the Location type (I recommend leaving it as multi-regional for higher
   performance and availability)
4. Choose Standard as the storage class
5. Select Uniform as the Access Control
6. Leave the rest as default and click Create

[Upload your assets directory to that bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects)

1. Open the Cloud Storage browser in the Google Cloud Console
2. In the list of buckets, click on the name of the bucket that you want to upload an object to.
3. In the Objects tab click the Upload Folder button, select the folder you want to upload in the dialog that appears, and click Open.

[Make your assets publicly readable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets)

1. Select the bucket from the list
2. Click on the three points setting icon at the right side and select "Edit bucket permissions"
3. Click on the Add Member button
4. Type **allUsers** in the "New members" field and select "Storage Object Viewer" as the Role
5. Click on the Save button and in Allow Public Access on the popup

[Reference the links on your page with the links provided by the bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data)

1. The public URL should be something like: https://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[DIR_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]. For example if you bucket is named ***assets*** and uploaded a folder named ***js*** with a file named ***main.js*** your public URL should be something like: https://storage.googleapis.com/assets/js/main.js

Comment: thank you! but the main problem is to add reference to the https://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[DIR_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME] in the INDEX.HTML of vue-project. I want to use filenameHashing for my assets in the Vue, so I need to update links dynamically every time when "npm run build" is running.

Comment: I would actually suggest turning off filenameHashing because the assets generated will change its name every time you build them, unless you're planning to upload the whole asset folder every time you build them, in which case I would recommend to use [Firebase](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#firebase) to have a better versioning control. Also please note that using GC Storage will be like using a CDN, so you have to make sure that references to filenames use the CDN URL